# How to store security certificate exception for webtest

Tags: performance, visualstudio

I am using Visual Studio 2015 to run a Web Performance test on our web site. The site uses SSL throughout. The tests run correctly on our 'production' site, but now I need to run them on our 'Staging' site. The staging site does not have a valid security certificate. When I run a webtest, I get the error: "Request failed: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" on every request.

In browsers (Firefox, Chrome), I can circumvent the 'Your connection is not secure' page by clicking on 'Advanced', and storing an exception. How can I do this in my performance tests?

What do I need to do to get my webtests running on the 'staging' site?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to my own question. Hope this helps others. What is needed is to force the underlying System.Net ServicePointManager to negotiate downlevel security. This can be done in a webtest plug-in. See this item "[SSL In webtests - VSTS 2008 and 2010](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e639498b-3e3b-4c47-8a38-b910a8be70fc/ssl-in-webtests-vsts-2008-and-2010?forum=vstswebtest)" in the MSDN forums. We are using this and have confirmed that it works with Visual Studio 2015 as well.

Comment: Initially the plugin failed for me when using Visual Studio 2013. I then used Fiddler to examine the responses to the "tunnel" requests and they showed TLS1.2 was wanted. So I set that protocol in the plugin and all seems OK now.